# In Laravel Backpack need to list users with specific role

Tags: roles, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

please check the details below, where I have a Organizations module. Where I can create a organization with a owner with role "organization".
[The third input is a dropdown where we need to select the user with role "organization"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncgTB.png)

```
protected function addOrganizationFields(){
    $this->crud->addFields([
        [
            'name'  => 'name',
            'label' => __('Organization Name'),
            'type'  => 'text',
        ],
        [
            'name'  => 'billing_information',
            'label' => __('Billing Information'),
            'type'  => 'textarea',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'owner_id',
            'label' => __('Organization Owner'),
            'type' => 'select2',
            'entity' => 'owners_list',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model' => "App\User",
        ]
    ]);
}
```

In the organization module I wrote this code.

```
public function owners_list(){        
    return User::whereHas('roles', function($q){
        $q->where('name', 'member');
    })->get();
}
```

in the Organization model relationship I wrote this.
But showing the list of all users in the drop-down.
Can anybody please tel me what is to be done.

Comment: Here I wanted to show the list of users with one specific role. Which is "organization"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate options from your select2 field using the “options” attribute mentioned in the docs - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields

```
    [
        'name' => 'owner_id',
        'label' => __('Organization Owner'),
        'type' => 'select2',
        'entity' => 'owners_list',
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'model' => "App\User",

        // add something like this

        'options'   => (function ($query) {
              return $query->whereHas('roles', function($q){
                              $q->where('name', 'member');
                         })->get();
         }), // force the related options to be a custom query, instead of all(); you can use this to filter the results show in the select
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is working with is.